# AUTH class not working php laravel (returns false)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-3

I have tried anything now.
In my auth.php i have set it to:

```
return array(
     'driver' => 'eloquent',
     'username' => 'email',
     'password' => 'password',
     'model' => 'User',
     'table' => 'users',
);
```

I will login the users by my column in database "email" and password "password"

Here is my user control class that checks the login, but it returns false everytime.

And yes $in['email'] is returning an email, and $in['password'] is a password. And yes, there is a record in database with that such of information.

```
        if ( Auth::attempt(array("username" => $in['email'], "password" => $in['password']))):
              echo "OK!";
         else:

             return Redirect::to('/users/login')->with_errors($v);

         endif;
```

Comment: Pretty sure:
Auth::attempt(array("username"
should be:
Auth::attempt(array("email"

You're authenticating against the email column.

Answer (score 0):

How do you create the password? 
Must be create using `Hash::make()`

Answer (score 0):

The Auth will return only false if the password is not Hash::make() made. I too was facing this issue but now fixed after creating the password using Hash::make();